# onActivityResult() does not get called inside TabActivity

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have created sub class of `TabActivity` and it contains four `TabHost` Tabs.

I just want to pick contact from my app, for this I am using the below code

```
private final int PICK = 2;
Intent intentContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); 
    parentActivity.startActivityForResult(intentContact, PICK);
```

Android Contact Picker screen call successfully, when I tap to any contact it redirect me to the last screen of my app where I called it but `onActivityResult` method does not get called.

In this regards I need your help. If I forget to mention anything please let me know.

Comment: And where is your onActivityResult method override? Is it in parentActivity?

Comment: No. It is on same Activity.

Comment: So this is an answer. You should call simple startActivityForResult (not parentActivity.startActivityForResult) or override onActivityResult in your parent activity. Now result is returning to it.

Comment: Can you send me sample code. It is good for me.

Comment: Done, but I really don't know what you want to see there..

Answer (score 1):

As you want here is some code stuff.

```
public class MyActivity extends TabActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // some other stuff

            TabHost.TabSpec firstTab = tabHost.newTabSpec("firstTab");

            firstTab.setContent(new Intent(this, FirstTabActivity.class)); // your class with content picker

            tabHost.addTab(firstTab);
    }
}
```

Here is an other

```
public class FirstTabActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final int PICK_REQUEST_CODE = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // some stuff

            Button pickContactButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_pick_contact);

            pickContactButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                            Intent intentContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                            startActivityForResult(intentContact, PICK_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
            });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if(PICK_REQUEST_CODE == requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                    // do some stuff
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [TabActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) has several strange behaviors, this might be one of them, you might workaround it to make it work, but I would definitely recommend you to start dropping it, it has been deprecated since API level 13. Read more about it:  (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html)

Comment: My app is pointing to API level 10. If I drop it my work will be wasted. Do you have any other alternative?

Comment: Android supportV4 package is compatible with Android 4 and later. So it is ok to use its futures.

Answer (score 0):

Other way of doing is this...

```
1.On button click(which you want to open intent) open another activity.
2.On another activity's onCreate() open that intent.
3.onActivityResult set static data which is on previous activity and call finish().
4.This way no one ever know that you opened such a activity and you ll get your data.
:)
```